# How to disable logging hibernate "Table not found" message

Tags: java, hibernate, logging

How do I disable logging output from Hibernate for:

```
HHH000262: Table not found: ...
```

I have the following log4j.properties:

```
log4j.rootLogger=WARN, stdout, stderr
log4j.logger.org.apache=WARN
log4j.logger.org.springframework=WARN

log4j.logger.org.hibernate=ERROR

log4j.appender.stdout = org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Threshold = TRACE
log4j.appender.stdout.Target   = System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern = %m%n
log4j.appender.stdout.filter.filter1=org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter
log4j.appender.stdout.filter.filter1.levelMin=TRACE
log4j.appender.stdout.filter.filter1.levelMax=INFO

# configure stderr for ERROR and WARN
log4j.appender.stderr = org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stderr.Threshold = WARN
log4j.appender.stderr.Target   = System.err
log4j.appender.stderr.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stderr.layout.ConversionPattern = %p: %m%n
```

The log4j.logger.org.hibernate=ERROR does eliminate other Hibernate INFO messages such as opening the database and such.  The "Table not found" messages are logged as INFO (I confirmed in the source code of hibernate).

I do not want to see the "Table not found" messages because I am using "update" mode to auto-create and update the tables.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there is a bug in the org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.DatabaseMetadata LOG static constant.  It is constructed like so...

```
private static final CoreMessageLogger LOG = Logger.getMessageLogger(CoreMessageLogger.class, DatabaseMetaData.class.getName());
```

The subtle bug is that the value passed into the category parameter is the DatabaseMetaData class (notice the capital D in MetaData), which is from the package java.sql.  As a result, you have to specify the logging level using...

```
log4j.logger.java.sql.DatabaseMetaData=WARN
```

Answer (score 0):

In Log4j you can specify a logging level for specified package, class or logger identified by string. You just simply write this in log4j.properties file:

```
log4j.logger.<your package> = DEBUG|INFO|OFF|WARN...
```

Comment: Isn't that what I'm doing with log4j.logger.org.hibernate=ERROR ?